# Choppy bluetooth sound

Tags: bluetooth, streaming

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Mac Mini and have extremely choppy sound when streaming and connected to a bluetooth speaker.  Sound is normal otherwise.   The video streams fine with no choppiness.   CPU and network utilization are high but not maxed out.   Any ideas would be appreciated.  Note that sound only streams fine, it is only with video that we get chop.

Comment: Not much action on my question...   I do have a solution, of sorts, namely to let it play for a while and the buffer, which seems to have been over filling and causing the choppiness, catches up with itself and the audio is ok.   At the start lips and audio are out of synch and choppy, at the end lips are in synch and the audio is not choppy.

Comment: The above is crap as I still have choppy sound.   Not sure why it is better some times than others.   Am now trying with the priority of pulseaudio set higher.   It would be nice if someone had a suggestion!

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17594133) it is likely that some apple hardware interferes with some other apple hardware. Please read and try the solutions presented there to confirm that it is a problem in Ubuntu, and not in the Apple devices.

Comment: I have given up on this and am letting the Apple be an Apple and got a Dell that is now an Ubuntu.   Bluetooth on the Dell works just fine!